# Passing constructor parameters to service when creating it with ServiceProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, service, .net-6.0, webapi

I have an ASP .Net 6 Web API. In it, I have a Singleton service which requires the use of a Transient service. So I inject IServiceProvider into the Singleton service, and then get an instance of the Transient service as follows:

```
using (var serviceScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    using (var service = (MyTransientService)serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyTransientService>())
    {
        // Use transient service
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to add some constructor arguments to my Transient service. How would I be able to provide these parameters when getting the service (as in the code above)?

I've searched the internet, but all examples I found show how to pass parameters when registering the service in Startup.cs (in the ConfigureServices() method), when knowing the values of the parameters upfront.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET Core built-in IoC does not offer this out-of-the-box. One option is to move the parameters from the constructor to the methods.

If you do not want to move the parameters to the methods, you can create and register a factory instead of the service. This factory can receive parameters in its `Create` method and instantiate the service:

```
public interface IServiceFactory
{
  IService Create(int i);
}

public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
  public IService Create(int i)
  {
    return new Service(i);
  }
}

services.AddSingleton<IServiceFactory, ServiceFactory>();

public class ServiceClient
{
  private readonly IServiceFactory _factory;

  public ServiceClient(IServiceFactory factory) 
  {
    _factory = factory;
  }

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      var svc = _factory.Create(i);
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Though the factory contains a plain `new` statement, this is not problematic because you can easily register another factory if you want to change the created type.

Comment: Thanks @Markus, two excellent suggestions. tixina3684 also suggested simply creating an instance of the transient service directly in the  singleton service. So I've got 3 suggestions to consider :)

Comment: You're welcome @FabricioRodriguez; the advantage of the approaches above is that you still have the option to change the implementation in the IoC later - the main point of having an IoC.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how Dependency Injection is used. If you need a "custom" `MyTransientService`, create a new Instance.

```
using (var service = new MyTransientService(/*Arguments*/))
{
    // Use service
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @tixina3674. Ok, I guess I didn't even consider creating an instance of the service the "simple way". I thought it was best practice, when requiring a scoped or transient service, from within a singleton service, to request the service using ServiceProvider (which in turn is injected into the Singleton service). But your proposal is a valid one, and should work just fine. I will probably go with it. Thanks!